# PHP crypt returns true even with suffix behind password

Tags: php, hash, passwords, crypt

So i have a small leak in my login script.

lets say we have a user "David" with the password "s3cret". If David logs in with s3cret, he is logged in, and everything works fine. If he logs in with "oijopij", the system won't give him access, as expected. However, If he tries to login with "s3cretHelloimasuffix", he is also logged in. This is the part where i create the hash with crypt:

```
$salt = //Some random salt string
$hash = crypt( $user->pass, $salt );
```

This hash is then inserted into the DB.

```
if ( crypt( $this->data->pass, $user->pass ) == $user->pass )
     return true;

return false;
```

This is then the part that actually checks the password against the hash, both the password, and the hash are correct. But it still returns true even if there is a suffix beghind the password.

edit: i forgot the actual question: How do i fix this problem? As it could be seen as a security leak, even though in practice it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`crypt` as you're using it is limited to 8 character passwords:

```
php > echo crypt('1234567', 'abc');
ablk9HoaAwzxk
php > echo crypt('12345678', 'abc');
ab1iBa.N.U2C6   
php > echo crypt('123456789', 'abc');
ab1iBa.N.U2C6
php > echo crypt('1234567890', 'abc');
ab1iBa.N.U2C6
```

Note how the ...8, ...89, ...890 versions have identical hashes.

`crypt` is obsolete and should not be used for password systems anymore. `password_hash()` is the recommended method now, which suports multiple hashing methods, including `bcrypt`, which SHOULD be used for password hashes.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll have a look into it. Great response, I wished I could give you more points than one.